# Can't find property 'exporter' while using Mat-Table-Exporter

Tags: html, angular

I'm working on a report page that displays the report based on the daterange entered by the user. The report is in tabular form and I want to export it to excel and csv files .
I'm using angular version 9 and trying to export the table data into xls, csv using [mat-table-exporter] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-table-exporter). The directive uses different exporter services for different exporting types.
But i'm getting this error in the html file that says "cannot read property 'exportTable' of undefined". Could you help me resolve the issue?

```html
<h3 align="center">Payment Gateway Report</h3>
<div class="container-fluid" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <ejs-daterangepicker placeholder="From and To Date"format='dd-MM-yyyy' [max]='maxDate' [(ngModel)]="date"></ejs-daterangepicker>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <button class="btn customBtn" (click)="getTableData()">Get Report</button>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" *ngIf="showTable">
            <button mat-button(click)="exporter.exportTable('csv')">Download</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="overflow: auto;" *ngIf="showTable">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;"#exporter="matTableExporter" matSort>
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="superMerchantName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> superMerchantName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.superMerchantName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="branchName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> branchName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.branchName}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="branchLoginId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header align="center"> branchLoginId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.branchLoginId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantUserId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantUserId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantUserId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantName</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="customerName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> customerName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customerName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="customerMobileNo">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> customerMobileNo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customerMobileNo}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="loanId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> loanId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.loanId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="paymentMode">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> paymentMode </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.paymentMode}} </td>
        </ng-container>

       
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="region">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> region </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.region}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="bankName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> bankName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bankName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cardScheme">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> cardScheme </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardScheme}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cardNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> cardNumber </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardNumber}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceImei">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> deviceImei </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deviceImei}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="latitude">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> latitude </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.latitude}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="longitude">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> longitude </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.longitude}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestedTimestamp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> requestedTimestamp </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestedTimestamp}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="responseTimestamp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responseTimestamp </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseTimestamp}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="remarks">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> remarks </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.remarks}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="stan">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> stan </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stan}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="statusCode">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> statusCode </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.statusCode}} </td>
        </ng-container>
      

        
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:   getDisplayedColumns();"></tr>
    
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: no, that won't be necessary since i'm using angular material

Comment: I went to that lib on github and did not see a property by that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about the way you are calling the template referance `exporter`.

A template referance is not accessible outside it's template scope.
By wrapping your table inside a structural directive (*ngIf) you happen to limit the template variable `#exporter` to be accessible only inside that div with *ngIf.

You can rather use CSS to show/hide your table instead of using ngIf. I wouldn't recommend it though.
The easiest and best way to resolve your issue is just simply put the button inside the same ng-template context.

For example this should work:

```
<h3 align="center">Payment Gateway Report</h3>

<div style="overflow: auto;" *ngIf="showTable">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;"#exporter="matTableExporter" matSort>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="superMerchantName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> superMerchantName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.superMerchantName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="branchName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> branchName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.branchName}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="branchLoginId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header align="center"> branchLoginId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.branchLoginId}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantUserId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantUserId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantUserId}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantName</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="customerName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> customerName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customerName}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="customerMobileNo">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> customerMobileNo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customerMobileNo}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="loanId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> loanId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.loanId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="paymentMode">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> paymentMode </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.paymentMode}} </td>
        </ng-container>



        <ng-container matColumnDef="region">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> region </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.region}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="bankName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> bankName </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bankName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cardScheme">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> cardScheme </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardScheme}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cardNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> cardNumber </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardNumber}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceImei">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> deviceImei </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deviceImei}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="latitude">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> latitude </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.latitude}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="longitude">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> longitude </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.longitude}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestedTimestamp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> requestedTimestamp </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestedTimestamp}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="responseTimestamp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responseTimestamp </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseTimestamp}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="remarks">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> remarks </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.remarks}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="stan">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> stan </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stan}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="statusCode">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> statusCode </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.statusCode}} </td>
        </ng-container>



        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:   getDisplayedColumns();"></tr>

    </table>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <ejs-daterangepicker placeholder="From and To Date"format='dd-MM-yyyy' [max]='maxDate' [(ngModel)]="date"></ejs-daterangepicker>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <button class="btn customBtn" (click)="getTableData()">Get Report</button>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" *ngIf="showTable">
                <button mat-button(click)="exporter.exportTable('csv')">Download</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

**EDIT:**

You forgot to add `matTableExporter` directive selector in your mat-table. It should be like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;" matTableExporter #exporter="matTableExporter" matSort>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error even after the change made: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Export of name 'matTableExporter' not found!
Error: Export of name 'matTableExporter' not found!

Comment: You need to make sure you imported MatTableExporterModule. I'm editing the answer accordingly.

Comment: i have imported it in app.module. I'm not sure why it is'nt recognizing it

Comment: OK, I finally saw it. :) you have to add matTableExporter selector for your mat-table element. Check the edit section.

Comment: ohh okay thanks. Now i'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentView' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentView' of undefined

Comment: This happens when your angular and cdk versions are not compatible with mat-table-exporter version. If you use angular 9 you should install the latest version of mat-table-exporter. If you use an older version of angular, say 8, you should be using mat-table-exporter@1.2.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216215/discussion-between-shivani-and-talhature).